# Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS: can't connect second monitor for display

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I partition my laptop to dual boot Mint and Ubuntu Studio. I use a monitor for second display, connected to the laptop via HDMI.

I know the monitor works, because it works fine when I run Mint.

When I boot into Studio, the login screen is fine for dual display. But once I log in, both screens are messed up. I can still see some images enough to make out the taskbar, and some minimal text, but it looks like the image is fragmented into small pieces and stacked on each other.

Please let me know how to fix it.

[picture of the laptop screen and second monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMFBe.jpg)

Edit 1:
For Mint, it's Mint 19.3 Tricia, Cinnamon Desktop Environment. I used the command you asked, and here are the printouts:

**UBUNTU STUDIO**

```
minh@minh-X555QA:~$ sudo lshw -C video
[sudo] password for minh:
  *-display                
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Wani [Radeon R5/R6/R7 Graphics]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
       version: ca
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:38 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f07fffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:feb00000-feb3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

**Mint**

```
minh@minh-X555QA:~$ sudo lshw -C video

[sudo] password for minh:

*-display

description: VGA compatible controller

product: Wani [Radeon R5/R6/R7 Graphics]

vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]

physical id: 1

bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0

version: ca

width: 64 bits

clock: 33MHz

capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom

configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0

resources: irq:34 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f07fffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:feb00000-feb3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

From what I can pick up, the resources: irq values are different (34 vs 38)

Comment: Mint is off-topic, but your use of it is actually useful if we know what software stack is found in the Mint (ie. what kernel is in use, what release it is or what Ubuntu it's based on).  Did you compare the kernel module (driver) in use in your Mint, and is it the same as used by your Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS?  (given your Ubuntu doesn't look very readable in pics, use a terminal to `sudo lshw -C video` or whatever tool you prefer).

Comment: @guiverc: thanks for your answer, I will edit my question to give the printout you asked.

Comment: @Minh lol, it's a comment. :)